# How to calculate the Bias of an estimate in a simulation study in R

Tags: r

I would like to calculate the bias between a population value and estimates in a simulation study using
[this formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tz64l.png):

[image]

Let the population value be b1=0.4. The estimates are a column of a data.frame of simulation results of two different methods and parameters.

| method | parameter | est |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | b1 | .4 |
| 2 | b2 | .32 |

This is what i tried:

```
#Bias
A <-c(data%>% filter (method== "1", parameter=="b1") %>% select(est))
bias(A, b1)
```

giving this error:

> ```
> Error in actual - predicted : non-numeric argument to binary operator
> ```

Comment: Try `A <- data %>% filter(method== "1", parameter=="b1") %>% pull(est)` - your method was returning a list rather than a single value. If that doesn't work, make sure the `est` column is numeric.

Comment: A looks better now, but the problem remains, that one is a vektor and the other is just one number. Do you know a solution for that? >                                           A <-data%>% filter (method== "data", parameter=="b1") %>% pull(est)
>  bias(b1, A)
Error in bias(b1, A) : 
  ncol(estimate) == length(parameter) is not TRUE

Comment: The `bias()` function should be averaging the estimates.  Are you using the `SimDesign` package, or did you get that function somewhere else?